# Get domain user name/Windows name of the Transaction executor using fn_dblog() in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know we can know the database user of the person who executed a certain transaction in SQL using fn_dblog(), but is it possible to get the domain user name or his windows user name if he is connecting using Windows authentication?

Thanks

Comment: Don't think so `[Transaction SID]` -> `sysusers` is the only info available that I can see.

Comment: Thats what I have read and seen in many places, too bad this function is not officially documented

Comment: This may help, but I'm totally unfamiliar with it: [Using fn_dblog, fn_dump_dblog, and restoring with STOPBEFOREMARK to an LSN](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/). @MartinSmith - thanks, I missed the bit on fn_dblog.

Comment: @Downvoter care to say why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible by using the fn_dblog, So I used SQL profiler to get everything I need. Check out the official documentation at [MSDN SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx.)

There is also a nice link with a small example that will help you get started at [Introduction to SQL Server 2008 Profiler](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/)